# npm update<package> doesn't update the package

Tags: npm, package

I've run into a issue where I try to update a package on a remote server, specifically the mongoose package.

If I run `npm mongoose --version` it will return a version number of `1.3.10`. However in `package.json` the version specified is `^2.7.4`.

I've tried to run `npm update` and it will not update the package to `^2.7.4`, as the version by `npm mongoose --version` still returns `1.3.10`

When I uninstall the package via `npm uninstall mongoose` it will return `unbuild mongoose@2.9.10`, but if I run `npm mongoose --version` it will still output `1.3.10`. I've tried reinstalling by a specific version number by `npm install mongoose@2.7.4` but `npm mongoose --version` will still return `1.3.10`

I've made sure that the `mongoose` package is not a global package, and I've tried to rebuild the entire `node_modules` folder by uninstalling all the packages and running `npm install`, but I still get a version number of `1.3.10`.

Any idea what it could be?

The remote server is running on `Ubuntu 14.04.2 LTS (GNU/Linux 3.16.0-38-generic x86_64)` if that helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the `npm --version` command actually returns the version number of `npm`.

What you actually want is to use `npm list mongoose` to list the version number of the package `mongoose` (`npm list` will display a list of all your packages with versions and `npm list -g` will display a list of all your global packages with their version number)

---

**Edit**

You could also use the command: `npm show {pkg} version`, in your case `npm show mongoose version`